# Angular UI components not "popping over" when injected into the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I'm trying to implement a few angular UI components into my simple angularjs application. When elements from the directives are entering the DOM they are shifting elements that are already there rather than popping over them. It seems that any directive that is meant to appear overtop of other elements are being displayed this way.

I'm a relatively new developer and there is a decent chance that I'm missing something easy and completely obvious. Any guidance is welcome.

I'm using angular 1.1.5 and ui-bootstrap 0.6.0 (with templates included).

Below are some screenshots to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Datepicker directive as it appears before opening:

[image: datepicker]

Datepicker after opening:

[image: after opening]

What it is suppose to look like upon opening([Link to plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1NDXTGzZQPXjeQAnDMb?p=preview)):

[image: plunker]

This example is from the tooltip directive which shows the same issue ("on the right" is meant to appear to the right of the text):

[image]

Last example using typeahead (names are meant to appear in a dropdown list):
[image: typeahead]

As mentioned earlier, any help or guidance is welcome- I would really like to get these working and have run dry for way to troubleshoot. Thanks!

Comment: Your plunker link points to the main plunker page.  Could you update it to point to what you were hoping to share?

Comment: Thanks, it should be fixed- It is just the example for the date picker from the angular UI page.